# Take snapshot / screenshot of UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How do I take a snapshot / screenshot of the `UIWebView` control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use This:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: When you are taking screenshot of a webview, it only takes screenshot of visible area. Hidden area is not taken into account.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is correct, however the screenshot is not in retina resolution. 
Using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and set its scale parameter 0.0f makes it capture in native resolution.

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 3):

use this code to take a screenshot and save it to the library

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, self, nil, nil);
```

you can change the screenshot taking portion by changing the

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
```

to your respective value
try it it will help you