# Efficiently take a snapshot of a large UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, snapshot

I've tried the following code to take a screenshot of a UIWebView whose bounds are larger than that of the screen (for example, around 1200pts), however the screenshot always comes out as the top part of the web view, stretched vertically downwards to cover the whole rect that it's supposed to draw. Any ideas? I could do it using -renderInContext:, but that's a slower and outdated method. Here's my current code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, scale);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
```

Comment: have you tried setting 'afterScreenUpdates:NO' ?

Comment: Yeah, in that case I just get a black screen

Comment: Mmm, I guess the problem is that the graphics of the UIWebView that are off screen, are not yet rendered to increase performance. So what you could do for example is take several screenshots, and use them as a commic book on a UIScrollView. Not sure if this would be faster than renderInContext however, which, you say does work?

Comment: I also found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9324716/3723434, which claims to give you a higher quality UIWebview screenshot. Haven't tried it.